# Fancybox : How change previous/next button by a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to change the previous and next button in a Fancybox by a link ??

This code work because it's the default button previous button :

```
<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>
```

I tried to replace the tag  with the text but it does not work

```
<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;">NEXT</a>
```

But not worked :(

Have you got solutions??

Thanks a lot for answer

Comment: What do you mean with *not worked*? What is the problem/error? Please edit your answer to show the code that you tried.

Comment: Both links are the same. How do you want to change it?

Comment: I have edited :D I want add in my fancybox  a link that replaces Boutton previous and Next .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for the default link not to work because of a simple change like that.

Here are a couple of things you can try:

- Take a look in the console and see if there isn't some JS error that breaks the execution, preventing the prev/next behavior.
- Make sure you only have one button for each direction in your code (I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of FancyBox but it's possible that only the first button selected works).
- If everything else fails you can add your own prev/next functionality using the provided Fancybox public methods: **$.fancybox.next**, **$.fancybox.prev** (http://fancybox.net/api)

Something along these lines:

```
var $fancyBoxedEl = $("#gallery").fancybox();

$('a.prev').click(function(){
    $fancyBoxedEl.prev();
    return false;
})
```

Hope this hepls.

Comment: Thank you very much , i use it : <a onclick="$.fancybox.prev"> Prévious </a> ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tpl` API option to set your texts like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
        next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span>NEXT</span></a>',
        prev: '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span>PREVIOUS</span></a>'
    }
});
```

and a bit of css to remove the default navigation buttons (and style your text) like :

```
.fancybox-nav span {
    background: 0 none !important;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6M5z5/)**